# Rails using .last and getting id one instead of first used id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When my app creates a new work order, it also creates the first task associated with that work order. The new task should have it's taskstatus set to the very first id in the Taskstatus table.

The first record in the Taskstatus table happens to have an id = 2.
But, the code sets the task.taskstatus_id = 1

Workorder Controller code:

```
  before_create :first_task

  protected
  def first_task
   self.tasks.build taskstatus_id: Taskstatus.first, taskname: self.description
  end
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!

UPDATE ----
The first record in the taskstatus table has id = 2.  The record with id = 1 was deleted.  I want the new task record to have a taskstatus_id = 2.

In the taskstatus.rb, I have:

```
  default_scope :order => 'id ASC'
```

This also created a task with taskstatus = 1

```
Taskstatus.limit(1)
```

I'm using postgreSQL.

On the taskstatus index page, 3 records display =

id  statuscode

2  New

3 Started

4 Completed

Something weird is happening!!

UPDATE 2 - You aren't going to believe this !!!!!! (I wouldn't) - but, it's true.

I changed the code to this:

```
Taskstatus.where(:statuscode => "New")
```

And even though New has id = 2, the task got 1

Could something be wrong with postgreSQL?

Comment: What do you mean by 'first', was there a record with an id of 1 that has been deleted?

Comment: It's true that the `frist` method in rails `3.2.x` does not actually return the first database record. This is dependent on the database engine you use. This is fixed in `rails/master` and will be available with rails 4. You can read up on the problem here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5103 A gist of the solution: first now adds a default order clause to always retrieve the element in the same order.

Comment: Yes, the record with id 1 was deleted. The lowest id is now 2.  I was expecting the results to be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have said,`.first` is un-ordered.

You can solve this by adding an explicit ordering (`.order(:id).first`), or by using a `default_scope` to *always* order the results:

```
class Taskstatus < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope order(:id)

end
```

Now `Taskstatus.first` will always be the first record, ordered by id. This may be useful if your ordering changes, and you wind up considering with one with the earliest `created_at` to be the "first" record.

Comment: This solution also gave me a taskstatus_id = 1.  But, there is no record with id =1.  It's been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Taskstatus.order("id").first
```

Comment: You don't need an explicit `limit(1)` because first on an AREL projection adds its own `limit(1)` clause. You also don't need to specify `ASC` in the ordering, that is implicit in the absence of a `DESC`.